# CSS: I can't center the body content in the background image

Tags: html, css, background, css-float

I tried to add a background to the body of the website, and I wanted to show the full background, and center the content of the website inside it.

I used the following CSS, but can't center it:

```
body {
  margin: auto;
  background: url(../images/bggeneral.jpg) top center repeat;
  background-position: center;
  font-size: 100%;
  line-height: 1.0625em;
  color: #515151;
  width: 100%;
}
```

the background image : http://www.comicar.ma/assets/images/bggeneral.jpg

Do I need to crop the image or something like that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can remove `repeat` if you dont want body image to be repeated. And `margin:0 auto` should be given to the container div.

**HTML**

```
<div class="wrapper">
Content
</div>​
```

**CSS**

```
body {background: url(http://www.comicar.ma/assets/images/bggeneral.jpg) top center no-repeat; font-size: 100%; line-height: 1.0625em; color: #515151; width: 100%; }
.wrapper{width:700px; margin:0 auto}
```

[**LIVE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/GZ3zx/)